# ¿Como se implementa la pasarela de pago de Google Play en Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación y quiero meterle una pasarela de pago para vender determinados servicios.
Hasta ahora he visto varias pasarelas como por ejemplo Stripe o Square, pero esto no es lo que busco.
Mi intención es que aparezca el típico boton de "Pagar con Google" o algo parecido y que te lleve a google play donde el usuario tiene ya introducida su tarjeta de crédito etc.
el problema es que no sé donde encontrar información al respecto, por más que busco no encuentro nada y no entiendo como puede estar la información tan oculta siendo algo tan comun.

No pretendo que me digais como hacerlo, si no saber donde mirar información al respecto y como se empezaria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe soporta Google Pay: https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay

Tambien existen plugins de Stripe para Flutter y Dart, por si prefieres utilizar esa integración directamente.

https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment

https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_sdk